# Git post-receive hook starts behaving strangely

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service, kudu

We have a number of websites hosted in Azure that are managed by git, each developer has a local repo and there's one bare origin repo on a shared network drive that we all have full access to. Deployment is handled by a post-receive hook in the origin repo that just does this:

```
git push https://login:pw@website.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/website.git HEAD:master
```

For pretty much all of these websites, this has worked fine for almost a year.  However!  Last month, one particular site started doing the below, most of the time *but not always*:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 125.22 KiB | 3.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: src refspec HEAD does not match any.
remote: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://login:pw@website.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/website.git'
```

If I just copy the exact contents of the post-receive hook and run that directly, it always works fine:

```
$ git push https://login:pw@website.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/website.git HEAD:master
(omitting all the usual git messages)
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: ...... (omitting deployment messages)
remote: Deployment successful.
```

If I try to investigate by adding a space somewhere and push to origin again, it works fine and deploys as intended: (note the double "remotes")

```
$ git push origin master
(omitting all the usual git messages)
remote: remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: remote: ...... (omitting deployment messages)
remote: remote: Deployment successful.
```

That is, it works fine until I give up investigating and then next week marketing needs us to urgently deploy some changes, then it refuses to work again.

I've looked at the various SO questions about this error and they mostly talk about empty cloned repos lacking a first commit, but these repos all have plenty of commits in them, and the branch names are all fine too (otherwise it wouldn't work at all, right?).  The fact that it works *sometimes* really bugs me... what could be the issue? Something to do with Kudu? I'd prefer to avoid just obliterating the website's git repository and recreating it; even if that solves the problem it means I never get a chance to *understand* the problem.

Comment: double remote should mean a post-receive hook of a remote remote repo triggered by the post-receive hook of the remote repo itself pushing.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that was why it had double remotes, I guess that must be the Azure repo's hook triggering Kudu to deploy the new code.

Comment: Try using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) and look under `D:\home\LogFiles\kudu\trace`. Do you get any entries in there when you get that error?

Comment: Couldn't access Kudu through website.scm.azurewebsites.net (403 error?), but I could get to that same directory using the normal web app console.  None of these logs indicate any kind of error, though.